# How do I pass instance of an object as an argument in a function in python?

Tags: python, oop

I am just starting to learn python and am getting confused about how to pass an instance of an object as an argument for a function, below is a little bit of code I made for practice and the basic idea is that there is one garage, this garage contains no cars, and you can add cars to the garage and view their details.

```
class Garage:
    cars = []

    def add_car(self, car):
        cars.append(car)

class Car:
    car_name, car_price, car_colour, car_miles, car_owners = "", "", "", "", ""

    def add_new_car(self, garage, name, price, colour, miles, owners):
        car_name = name
        car_price = price
        car_colour = colour
        car_miles = miles
        car_owners = owners

        garage.add_car(self)

def main(argv=None):    
    your_garage = Garage()

    while True:
        print "Your garage contains %d cars!" % len(your_garage.cars)
        print "1) Add a new car\n2) View your car's\n0) Leave the garage"
        user_input = raw_input("Please pick an option: ")

        if user_input == "1":
            add_car(your_garage)
        elif user_input == "2":
            view_cars(your_garage)
        elif user_input == "0":
            quit()

def add_car(garage):
    name = raw_input("Name: ")
    price = raw_input("Price: ")
    colour = raw_input("Colour: ")
    miles = raw_input("Miles: ")
    owners = raw_input("Owners: ")

    car = Car()
    car.add_new_car(garage, name, price, colour, miles, owners)

def view_cars(garage):
    for x in xrange(len(garage.cars)):
        print garage.cars[x].car_name
        print garage.cars[x].car_price
        print garage.cars[x].car_colour
        print garage.cars[x].car_miles
        print garage.cars[x].car_owners

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

My code might be very wrong or there might be an easy way to do this, I the way I pictured it was going to be that the new instance of car I created would be passed into the add_car() function in Garage so that it can be added to the list of cars. How can I do this?

Comment: I believe you can do this in Java by just passing method(this), and then 'this' being the instance of the object would be passed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe this simplified example will point you in the right direction. One of the main problems in your current code is that you should be setting instance-level attributes (for example, a car's color or a garage's inventory of cars) inside the `__init__` method (or in some other method operating on instances), not up at the class level.

```
class Garage:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cars = []            # Initialize instance attribute here.

    def add_car(self, car):
        self.cars.append(car)

class Car:
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color        # Ditto.

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Car(color={})".format(self.color)

def main():
    g = Garage()
    for color in 'red green blue'.split():
        car = Car(color)
        g.add_car(car)        # Pass the car to the garage's add_car method.
    print g.cars            # [Car(color=red), Car(color=green), Car(color=blue)]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```