# Pass a Class as an argument to another Class

Tags: python, class

I've just started using Python and learning about classes at the moment. I'm wondering if I can pass a Class as an argument to another Class.
I've created 2 Classes - class Point and class Circle.
I want Circle to take a Point with coordinates x and y and a radius as arguments.

```
class Point:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        return

#  Takes a Point with coordonates x,y as center, and a radius
class Circle:

    def __init__(self, Point, radius):
        self.Point = Point
        self.radius = radius
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass instance of an object as an argument in a function in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20725699/how-do-i-pass-instance-of-an-object-as-an-argument-in-a-function-in-python)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You wouldn't pass the class name, rather you'd pass an instance of that class

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Circle:
    def __init__(self, point, radius):
        self.point = point
        self.radius = radius
```

The usage of these classes would then look something like

```
point = Point(3, 5)
circle = Circle(point, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `__init__` method of your class Circle, you confuse the variable-name of parameter "point" with its Class (type) you want it to be.

What you can do is to check the type of your parameter "point" in the `__init__` method like so:

```
class Circle:
    def __init__(self, point, radius):
        if not type(point) == Point:
            raise ValueError('Parameter point must be of type Point.')
        self.point = point
        self.radius = radius
```

In python you are not forced to specify the type for parameters in the method header, like you would do in other programming languages like Java.

But, if you use python 3+ you can add so called "type hinting" to your parameters. This helps to spot type error before you run the code, if your IDE supports it.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

You could "type-hint" your parameter "point" like so:

```
class Circle:
    def __init__(self, point: Point, radius):
        if not type(point) == Point:
            raise ValueError('Parameter point must be of type Point.')
        self.point = point
        self.radius = radius
```